# Query column values without column names in sqflite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a table where I stock latitude and longitude. I need these values to use them in LatLng(latitude, longitude).
When I use this function :

```
Future<List> getLatitude() async {

  var geoloc = await database;

  var result = await geoloc.rawQuery('SELECT lat FROM Geoloc');

  return result.toList();
}
```

I get something like this :

```
{{lat: 44.7949447}, {lat: 44.7949512}, {lat: 44.7949696}, {lat: 44.7949648}, {lat: 44.7949703}, {lat: 44.7949715},
```

However, I don't want the column name 'lat' I only want the values. I'm kinda stuck here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
return result.map((i) => i["lat"]).toList();
```

if you one a `List<double>` as return value

```
return List<double>.from(map2.map((i) => i["lat"]).toList()).toList();
```